# Adjusting qooxdoo scrolling speed/sensitivity

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm wondering if it is possible to adjust the scrolling sensitivity in qooxdoo applications using `qx.ui.container.Scroll` or any internally scrollable components, e.g. `qx.ui.table.Table`.

What I'm experiencing on my MacBook Pro running Sierra 10.12.3 is a blazing fast scrolling speed using the trackpad, and it only appears to be the case in qooxdoo-based applications which makes them very difficult to use. Tried different browsers with comparable results (Chrome, Safari, ...).

As an example, open the [API browser](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.2/api/index.html) and scroll the browsing API tree on the left.

Comment: BTW, as I can remember, MacOS sierra changed something to the mouse wheel events that were delivered to the applications by the system. It broke a lot of stuff including scrolling in Java applications or the native Terminal app itself. It may be related and qooxdoo code might need some adjustments regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qooxdoo does some efforts to normalize mouse wheel delta across browser platforms. The two finger swipe gestures on the trackpad in OSX seem to be exposed as wheel events to safari, which may not be optimally normalized. Mouse wheel events caused by turning a real mouse wheel do not seem to cause that blazing scrolling speed.

The code where normalization happens is located at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/util/Wheel.js

The normalization routines are not exposed as an API and are not configurable. To solve this issue the normalization code needs to be adjusted.

It would be best to open an issue for this in the github issue tracker at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues

Here is a jsfiddle which writes the event type and delta down to the console for mouse wheel events. This may be a starting point for investigating the delta values of wheel events on different platforms:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfe8J/77/

```
function wheelSpeed(event) {
    var delta;
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        delta = event.wheelDelta;
    } else {
        delta = event.deltaY ? event.deltaY : event.detail;
    }
    console.log("event type: "+ event.type + ", delta: " + delta);
    return delta;
}
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheelSpeed);
window.addEventListener('wheel', wheelSpeed);
```

A proposal for a solution or best a pull request which solves the issue would be greatly appreciated and welcome.